# How to make multiple menues in Orchard CMS

Tags: menu, orchardcms

I would like to make a content based sub navigation on some pages in Orchard 1.4, but i don't know how. Can I achieve this by using Advanced Menu Module or any other module? 
Or is there a way to get this done without a module?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find out a way to do it?

Comment: Well i had to use th Advanced Menu Module, and make some Widgets with different Menus.. Quite complicated. i hope there will be another solution provided by Orchard itself soon :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a module. (some random text to make SO happy)